# Why isn't vectorization making this faster?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

Below I have two versions of code to get to the same output - I am running through a list of possible number combinations, finding which filters would make each combination true, and then finding only unique filters (e.g., filter (5,6) (5,6) (5,6) is not unique, in that it would 'pass' all the same combinations as filter (5,7) (5,7) (5,7)

I was reading that vectorization can speed up processes, so I've tried that below, after my simple for loop.  The vectorization is much slower.  So much slower, I must be doing something wrong (but still getting the same correct result).

Any help would be appreciated.
(Also, not sure why finding unique values after the vectorization took so long in the output below)

```
#########################################
### Compare for loop to vectorization ###
#########################################
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
import time

size_value = 8
#df = pd.DataFrame({'var_1_lower_limit':[1,2,1,3,2],'var_1_upper_limit':[5,5,4,7,6],'var_2_lower_limit':[5,5,3,6,4],'var_2_upper_limit':[9,9,8,9,7],'var_3_lower_limit':[6,7,4,2,4],'var_3_upper_limit':[8,8,6,8,7]})
df = pd.DataFrame({'var_1_lower_limit':np.random.randint(0,5,size=size_value),'var_1_upper_limit':np.random.randint(5,10,size=size_value),'var_2_lower_limit':np.random.randint(0,5,size=size_value),'var_2_upper_limit':np.random.randint(5,10,size=size_value),'var_3_lower_limit':np.random.randint(0,5,size=size_value),'var_3_upper_limit':np.random.randint(5,10,size=size_value)})
df.sort_values(['var_1_lower_limit','var_1_upper_limit','var_2_lower_limit','var_2_upper_limit','var_3_lower_limit','var_3_upper_limit'],ascending=True, inplace=True) # I think important to sort here
display(df)


########## for loop
checkpoint_01 = time.perf_counter()
print('Beginning for loop run...')
default_possibilities = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
possibilities = list(itertools.product(default_possibilities,default_possibilities,default_possibilities,default_possibilities,default_possibilities,default_possibilities)) #Creates all combinations of possibilities
print('length of possibilities',len(possibilities))
possibilities = [item for item in possibilities if item[1]>=item[0] and item[3]>=item[2] and item[5]>=item[4]] # removes combinations that don't make sense such as first value is 5 and second value is 3
print('length of revised possibilities',len(possibilities))

filtering_output = []
checkpoint_02 = time.perf_counter()
for i in possibilities:
  a = i[0]
  b = i[1]
  c = i[2]
  d = i[3]
  e = i[4]
  f = i[5]
  for z in df.itertuples():
    if z.var_1_lower_limit <=a and z.var_1_upper_limit >=b and z.var_2_lower_limit <=c and z.var_2_upper_limit >=d and z.var_3_lower_limit <=e and z.var_3_upper_limit >=f:
      filtering_output.append({'combination':i,'var_1_lower_limit':z.var_1_lower_limit,'var_1_upper_limit':z.var_1_upper_limit, 'var_2_lower_limit':z.var_2_lower_limit,'var_2_upper_limit':z.var_2_upper_limit,'var_3_lower_limit':z.var_3_lower_limit,'var_3_upper_limit':z.var_3_upper_limit,'pass_or_fail':'YES'})
    else:
      continue

filtering_output_df = pd.DataFrame(filtering_output)
checkpoint_03 = time.perf_counter()
print('Iteration loop time was',(checkpoint_03-checkpoint_02)/60,'minutes')
unique_combinations = filtering_output_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['combination'], keep='first')
final_filters = unique_combinations.drop_duplicates(subset=['var_1_lower_limit','var_1_upper_limit','var_2_lower_limit','var_2_upper_limit','var_3_lower_limit','var_3_upper_limit'], keep='first') # since df was sorted, keeping only filters that had a passing combination
checkpoint_04 = time.perf_counter()
print('Done finding unique',(checkpoint_04-checkpoint_03)/60,'minutes')
display(final_filters)
checkpoint_05 = time.perf_counter()
print('Total time for loop',(checkpoint_05-checkpoint_01)/60,'minutes')

######### vectorization
checkpoint_06 = time.perf_counter()
print('Starting vectoriation...')
default_possibilities_new = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6)))
print('Length of default possibilities',len(default_possibilities_new))

mask_new = (default_possibilities_new[:, 1] >= default_possibilities_new[:, 0]) & \
       (default_possibilities_new[:, 3] >= default_possibilities_new[:, 2]) & \
       (default_possibilities_new[:, 5] >= default_possibilities_new[:, 4])

possibilities_new = default_possibilities_new[mask_new]
print('length of revised possibilties',len(possibilities_new))

filtering_output_new = []
checkpoint_07 = time.perf_counter()
for i in possibilities_new:
    mask_new = (
            (df['var_1_lower_limit'] <= i[0]) & (df['var_1_upper_limit'] >= i[1]) &
            (df['var_2_lower_limit'] <= i[2]) & (df['var_2_upper_limit'] >= i[3]) &
            (df['var_3_lower_limit'] <= i[4]) & (df['var_3_upper_limit'] >= i[5])
    )

    if mask_new.any():
        row = df[mask_new].iloc[0]
        filtering_output_new.append({
            'combination': i,
            'var_1_lower_limit': row['var_1_lower_limit'],
            'var_1_upper_limit': row['var_1_upper_limit'],
            'var_2_lower_limit': row['var_2_lower_limit'],
            'var_2_upper_limit': row['var_2_upper_limit'],
            'var_3_lower_limit': row['var_3_lower_limit'],
            'var_3_upper_limit': row['var_3_upper_limit'],
            'pass_or_fail': 'YES'
        })

filtering_output_df_new = pd.DataFrame(filtering_output_new)
checkpoint_08 = time.perf_counter()
print('Done with vectorization',(checkpoint_08-checkpoint_06)/60,'minutes')
unique_combinations_new = filtering_output_df_new.drop_duplicates(subset=['combination'], keep='first')
final_filters_new = unique_combinations_new.drop_duplicates(subset=['var_1_lower_limit', 'var_1_upper_limit', 'var_2_lower_limit', 'var_2_upper_limit', 'var_3_lower_limit','var_3_upper_limit'], keep='first')
checkpoint_09 = time.perf_counter()
print('Done finding unique',(checkpoint_09-checkpoint_08)/60,'minutes')
display(final_filters_new)

checkpoint_10 = time.perf_counter()
print("Vectorization done in", (checkpoint_10 - checkpoint_06)/60,'minutes')
```

Output
[image]

Comment: `itertools.product(default_possibilities, reapeat=6)`

Comment: no need to create a list: `list(itertools.product(...))`, use the generator in the for loop, no need to print its length

Comment: create a generator expression to filter and use that in the final for loop (checkpoint_02)

Comment: why is the display of a dataframe part of the time measured

Comment: `else: continue` is useless

Comment: finding unique in the vectorization takes 15min, how big is that df compared to the for loop version. on my computer vectorization duplicate removal crashes (something is not hashable), I have times a generator version of for loop and it is 0.2 sec slower on 64 sec total

Comment: in vectorization you calculate all 48 bool tests, in for-loop-if you skip bool tests at first one that fails

Comment: `a,b,c,d,e,f = i` is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved 'Done with vectorization' by removing the loop. The frame data is turned into a numpy array. `mask_faster` gets a boolean mask for each row (each column is a mask for selecting rows from the dataframe - this is what you did in the loop).

In `bl` there is a mask if at least one is true. `index` indexes for retrieving array rows from `arr`. **mask_faster** is overwritten by masks bl:  `mask_faster[:, bl]`. In `new_df`, the necessary values are filled in through list comprehension. As a result, 60-70 times faster.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

dpn = default_possibilities_new[mask_new]

checkpoint_mask_faster = time.perf_counter()

mask_faster = (
            (df['var_1_lower_limit'].values[:, np.newaxis] <= dpn[:, 0]) &
            (df['var_1_upper_limit'].values[:, np.newaxis]  >= dpn[:, 1]) &
            (df['var_2_lower_limit'].values[:, np.newaxis]  <= dpn[:, 2]) &
            (df['var_2_upper_limit'].values[:, np.newaxis]  >= dpn[:, 3]) &
            (df['var_3_lower_limit'].values[:, np.newaxis]  <= dpn[:, 4]) &
            (df['var_3_upper_limit'].values[:, np.newaxis]  >= dpn[:, 5])
    )

bl = np.any(mask_faster, axis=0)
index = np.where(bl)[0]
arr = df.values
mask_faster = mask_faster[:, bl]

new_df = pd.DataFrame([{'combination': dpn[index[i]],
                        'var_1_lower_limit': arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0][0],
                        'var_1_upper_limit': arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0][1],
                        'var_2_lower_limit': arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0][2],
                        'var_2_upper_limit': arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0][3],
                        'var_3_lower_limit': arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0][4],
                        'var_3_upper_limit': arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0][5],
                        'pass_or_fail': 'YES'
                        } for i in range(mask_faster.shape[1])])

print('Done with mask_faster',(time.perf_counter()-checkpoint_mask_faster)/60,'minutes')
```

You can also check your dataframe result with mine:

```
print('comparison of dataframes', new_df.equals(filtering_output_df_new))
```

The slowest part is `unique_combinations_new`, I think because there is a list in each line. I tried it using [np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and I’m not exactly sure if it works the same as `drop_duplicates`, but it works very quickly. You need to check this:

```
ind_uniq = np.unique(dpn[index], axis=0, return_index=True)[1]

unique_combinations_new = new_df.loc[ind_uniq, :]
```

Comment: thanks so much.  What a help!  Now for one more edit, if you can help.  [br] I'm adding two more fields to df --> count_of_records and dollar_value.  In new_df, I want to return the cumulative sum of the count_of_records and dollar_value that have pass_or_fail == Yes.  I tried 'count_of_records': arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0][6].cumsum() hoping that might work, but that was just a stab.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Jim arr[mask_faster[:,i]][0] are 6 values from var_1_lower_limit to var_3_upper_limit for the row with index **i**. Do you need cumsum() on those 6 values for each row(then it will be a list of 6 values) or cumsum() on a specific column starting from row 0 to the last?
And in new_df all 'pass_or_fail' are equal to 'YES'.

Comment: it would be cumsum() on count_of_records and dollar_value, for all the rows where pass_or_fail == 'YES' for each i in possibilities.  In other words, for each iteration of possibilities, there could be up to 8 rows that are YES (size of df is 8), and I would need cumsum() of all those eight

Comment: **'count_of_records': np.cumsum(arr[mask_faster[:,i]], axis=1)** when axis=1 the cumulative sum is calculated by row along the columns, if you need to count each column row axis=0

Comment: Or do need a cumulative sum for example in the 'var_3_upper_limit' column? Then it's simple: new_df['cums'] = new_df['var_3_upper_limit'].cumsum()

Comment: Thanks @ inquirer.  I was able to figure out what I was looking for (and not explaining well), which is 
'count_of_records':arr[mask_faster[]:,i]][:, 6].sum().  But again, thanks for all the help on this.

Comment: You just needed the sum. cumsum is a moving sum. Also note that arr is a numpy array it is not pandas. If you need all the options that fall (at each iteration all selected from 8 possible rows), then you can do this: np.sum(arr[mask_faster[:,i]], axis=1) and therefore numpy methods are applied to it, such as np.sum.  In terms of speed, pandas is noticeably inferior to numpy. But pandas is much more convenient because it works with heterogeneous data.